# DNF/YUM: Is there a way to install the latest version of package, without specifying the version?

Tags: package-management, yum, dnf, version

From browsing and reading docs I think the answer is going to be no, and that I'll just have to specify versions...

However is there a way to get the latest version of a package?

Any tricks you might use?

I mean some kind of option like `--latest`, I vaguely remember `apt` having something like that, but might just be imagining things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNF/YUM work **only** with what's available in **enabled** repositories. If a certain installed package is older than what's available in repos, the latest/newest version in repos will be installed if you run `yum/dnf update`. That's it.

If you want to install the latest upstream version you you have the following options:

- Difficulty: the easiest. Find and install any pre-packaged version as FlatPak, Snap, AppImage or Docker image. This can co-exist with an already installed package.
- Difficulty: easy. Find and enable a [COPR](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) (for e.g. Fedora) with the latest version if such a COPR exists. Any person in the world can build such packages, so do exercise **caution**.
- Difficulty: average. Install from sources to e.g. `/usr/local`, `/opt/package` or even `/home/user/something`.
- Difficulty: high. Create your own src.rpm package, compile it and update to it (if it doesn't conflict with already installed packages). You can make src.rpm install to any location and name differently (e.g. instead of package-2.3.4 you can name it package2-2.3.4) to avoid conflicts with any installed packages.